# Help me setup vpn on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vpn

How Can I install **GUI** VPN on Ubuntu 14.04 ? I've tried many ways but it seems so different from Microsoft windows any help please I'm a total beginner

Comment: What do you mean by "GUI VPN"?  A GUI VPN *client* so you can connect to a VPN, or a GUI VPN *server* so you can receive connections from other locations to the server over VPN?

Comment: GUI VPN so I can connect to a VPN @Thomasw.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of VPN. You may need to consult your VPN provider's documentation, or contact their support services to find out what type of VPN it is.

#### For a "vpnc" VPN:

Open a terminal (Alt-Ctrl-T) and type the following command, entering your password when prompted:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

#### For an "openvpn" VPN:

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Then reboot your computer, and right-click on the network-manager icon in the taskbar. There should be a VPN option either in this menu, or under the "Add new connection" options.

Comment: It's going good but not connected still @Nick Weinberg

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please be more specific about what you've tried, what's working, what's not working, any error messages, or specific questions. @Meyer

Comment: The VPN is not connected with these steps @NickWeinberg